# Windows form Setup unable to load dll

Tags: vb.net, winforms, deployment, dllimport, setup-deployment

I have an windows application which uses third party dll Velleman.dll it works fine. when i created setup file even it works fine. but when the setup file run in other system (then one in build) it throws the exception : Unable to load DLL 'Velleman.dll'
what might be the error?

Comment: Either the DLL is not in the install package or in you code you refer to it using specific path. Use relative path whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of possibilities here.

Is Velleman.dll a COM dll?
If so you will should register it in the registry on the other system during your application installation.

Is it a .NET dll?
If so, you will need to make sure it is included in the installer.